# Retrieving Recommends for blog entry: Method not allowed

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to retrieve a feed of recommenders for a blog entry as described in the API documentation here:

http://www-0.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Getting_a_list_of_recommenders_ic40a&content=pdcontent

Problem is, I always get a http 405: method not allowed. Is this a known problem? Am I doing anything wrong? To be more precise, I am dealing with entries of an ideation blog here. My request is authenticated with the owner of the community and ideation blog.

Comment: Do you get the 405 in the browser or from making the API call in your app?

Comment: sadly for both, i also tried RestClient Addon for firefox - same result

Comment: I am making various calls to the Api from our Java app, retrieving a community, the blog inside the community and its entries. This all works well, and even the COMMENTS url from the very same entry feed returns results.

Comment: are you making a call against a production server? or perhaps it's behind a reverse proxy? maybe you should check via direct access? also did you try the GET operation with the proper request type? I imagine you didn't set the request-type

Comment: No luck with direct access, I'm still facing the same 405. What do you mean with request type? The method of the request is GET, it's authenticated via Basic Authentication and I dont use any other headers. Is there anything necessary, that I'm not aware of? I'm espacially baffled because all the other requests (for comments of an entry as well as the comment's likes among various other things) are working flawlessly.

Comment: Type content-type = application/atom+xml

Comment: Although I thought GET requests are never required to definde content-type headers, I tried your suggestion; sadly without any luck. Do you know if get requests for recommendations are really possible for the special blog type ideation blog? I'm getting the feeling, that something's just not right here :-/

Comment: Okay, I just tried it for a non-ideation blog entry and it simply worked. The api documentation suggests, that this should work for ideation blogs exactly like it does for any blog http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Vote_an_idea&content=pdcontent. Can someone assure me, that the API side is really working as described there?

Comment: you just want to get the list of voters. Then this api worked for me....https://<SERVERNAME>/blogs/<COMMUNITYID>/feed/entryrecommendations/<IDFORENTRY>/atom?lang=en_us

Comment: thank you very much for the input! I also get a response from this URL but had to replace <COMMUNITYID> with <BLOGID> actually. The Result itself sadly does not contain the voters but an empty feed, which nonetheless states <opensearch:totalResults>3</opensearch:totalResults> I'm looking into this issue now. Aside from that, I would be very interested, where I could have found the API you mentioned. I did not read anything about that in the documentation; following the link in the atom entry for the blogentry itself, leads to https://<SERVER>/blogs/<BLOGID>/api/recommend/entries/<ENTRYID>

Comment: I always look at the bottom of the document I want and look at the feed list and look at the atom subscription to find the api / url I want

Comment: I checked this again, and those are my results: as mentioned, the url you provided gives me an empty feed with <opensearch:totalresults> tag for an ideation blog. for a "regular" blog (same community, same user, who is also owner), it gives me a complete feed containing <author> entries for every person who recommended. Any idea what's still wrong here?

Comment: @PaulBastide thanks for your hint at the feed links in connections. this really helps! not in this exact example though, since i can only get comments and entry feeds there, but this surely is a convenient way to get to API urls for Connections!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is a composition of comments from Benny and I - https:///blogs//api/recommend/entries/  enable one to find the details of the blog votes.

Comment: sorry, but this still gives me an empty feed (see comment above) for _ideation blogs_. For normal blogs, the feed contains <author> entries for every recommender, but not for ideation blogs. I might still have something wrong here, or the API isnt just giving this away